# Regular expression for finding custom tags

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression that matches some custom tags from a text. The tags always have the format [!--sometext--] or [!--sometext:param1--], [!--sometext:param1:param2--]. What I need to do is fetch the "sometext" part and the optional params as "param1:param2" or "param1" and "param2" separately (doesn't matter).

My approach for tags without params is

`\[!--(.+?)--\]`

but how do I match the params part in an elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** OK, third time should be the charm, right? ;-) This works for me in a sample Perl script.

This should do it (and I'm assuming a Perl-compatible reg-ex ... you don't specify what language you're writing this in):

```
\[!--([^\]:]+):?([^\]-]+?)?--\]
```

What's going on here?

1. First we match the `[!--`
2. Then we do a match (and capture) on anything that's not a `:` or a `]`
3. Then we match an optional colon
4. Then we have an optional, non-greedy match (and capture) of anything that's not either a `-` or a `]` (this should capture all the optional parameters at once)
5. Then we end it by matching `--]`

You'll need to split the optional parameters on `:` to catch the case where there might be more than one.

Comment: I had something similar to that, but then

`Blah [!--disclaimer_vat--] blupp [!--disclaimer_vat--]`

would produce a match for

`disclaimer_vat--] blupp [!--disclaimer_vat` because of greediness.

Comment: I changed it to a non-greedy variant. See if that works for you. I guess you could also make sure you don't hit a closing `]` in the final captured match: `([^\]-]+?)?`